# How to get the index of an item in an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am trying to display all available font families on the user's system in a `JComboBox`. I have a string array as follows:

```
String fontsList[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

This gets the fonts on the user's system, and all is fine except when I want to select the default selected option, which should be 'Helvetica'.

```
JComboBox fontsDisplay = new JComboBox(fontsList)
fontsDisplay.setSelectedIndex(**Set selected index to helvetica**);
```

I tried iterating over the fonts and adding them to an `ArrayList`, but there is no method to get a certain string in the list. Is there a way to get a string item in the `ArrayList`? I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
fontsList.getString("Helvetica")
```

It gets a string element in the array `fontsList` and searches for 'Helvetica.'

Comment: @snvrthn How would a map apply? This is a list, no need for a map of any sort, nor is a map ever returned by the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select the default selected option, which should be Helvetica.

Well, `"Helvetica"` isn't found in my list of available font family names.

But assuming it is a valid value on your system then you can just specify the String as the object you want to select:

```
    comboBox.setSelectedItem("Helvetica"); // which may be on your system
    //comboBox.setSelectedItem("Arial"); // which works on my system
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use indexOf() to get the position of the element from a list.

```
String fontsList[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

JComboBox<String> fontsDisplay = new JComboBox<>(fontsList);
fontsDisplay.setSelectedIndex(Arrays.asList(fontsList).indexOf("Helvetica"));
```

Comment: What a good use of the `utils.Arrays` class. This is better than mine :)

Comment: @AndrewL, why create a wrapper class by using the Arrays.asList(...) method when the functionality is built directly into the JComboBox API?

Answer (score 1):

Get the index, and get the object. Using [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) and [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)):

```
fontsDisplay.setSelectedIndex(list.get(list.indexOf('Helvetica')));
```

You might want to do some error checking here, to catch the classic `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case the `list.indexOf` method returns `-1` because the font is missing.